# How to split a string at forward slash OR backward slash VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, split

I am currently splitting a string at every occurrence of a forward slash. In the case of a path that uses backward slashes instead of forward slashes, how can I accomplish the split function at all backward slashes if they are instead used? Thanks for any help.

```
Dim p() as string
p = Split(strP, "/")'Or backward slash
```

Comment: You should use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w) class instead. For example: `Dim folders = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p = someString.Split("/"c, "\"c)
```

Comment: Hah! I never realized that the String Split method was so different from the old VB Split() function. Learn something new everyday.